# Enabling Visibilty to other Clients on a Medialink Wireless N Router

Tags: networking, security, router, wireless-router

After some trouble with my Buffalo router, I switched to a Medialink Wireless N Router.  (I was sad to lose dd-wrt, but the Medialink had great reviews on Amazon and a good price point.)

The issue I've run into is that none of my devices on the wireless network can access each other.  For example, I cannot file share from my laptop to my desk, nor can I still do things like have my iPhone control my Apple TV or Apple TV access my desktop iTunes.

My hunch is this is a simple security setting, but I've been banging my head against the wall for an hour now.  Any advice?  If there's an official networking term for what I want to do, that would at least help with my searching.

Answer (score 1):

That particular feature or bug is called 'AP isolation'.

Quoting a cisco forum member [sharkbyte](http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/AP-isolation/td-p/23327):

> AP Isolation: Creates a separate virtual network for your wireless network. When this feature is enabled, each of your wireless client will be in its own virtual network and will not be able to communicate with each other. You may want to utilize this feature if you have many guests that frequent your wireless network.